# Cannot dynamically set workspace mappings for custom build

Tags: tfsbuild

When I run the following a new build is queued but does not have my new mappings.

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection server = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUri));
        IBuildServer buildServer = server.GetService<IBuildServer>();
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = server.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects[projectArea];
        IBuildDefinition buildDef = buildServer.GetBuildDefinition(teamProject.Name, buildDefininition);
        IBuildRequest requestedBuild = buildDef.CreateBuildRequest();

        var mapping = requestedBuild.BuildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings[0];
        mapping.LocalItem = mapping.LocalItem.Replace("OLD", "NEW");
        mapping.ServerItem = mapping.ServerItem.Replace("OLD", "NEW");
        requestedBuild.BuildDefinition.Workspace.RemoveMapping(requestedBuild.BuildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings[0]);
        requestedBuild.BuildDefinition.Workspace.AddMapping(mappingT.ServerItem,mappingT.LocalItem,mappingT.MappingType);
        buildServer.QueueBuild(requestedBuild);
```

I cannot understand why the build server is not using my new mappings. Setting a break point before then QueueBuild call shows the mappings are my new values. Is it not possible to do this dynamically? All the examples I have seen have saved the build definition first or not changed the mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only changed an in-memory object: QueueBuild will put in the queue a pointer to the saved definition.

If you do not want to make your change permanent, by saving before QueueBuild, you must resort to customize the Xaml Build Template (e.g. by adding a DownloadFile).
Keep in mind that, normally, the user account running the Build has complete access to Version Control.

Comment: Its a bit counter intuitive, the parameter really should be the build name or id. There is more information at the bottom of this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/03/25/tfs2010-queuing-a-build-from-code-with-custom-process-parameter-values.aspx which details how the three layers of build definition override each other.